# Django ModelChoiceField to_field_name is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have following models and i'm trying to use Django ModelForm's ModelChoiceField to solve my problem quickly

```
Class Games(Model):
   code = charField()  # GTA, ABC, etc..
   name = charField()  # Grand Tourismo, ALL BBB CCC , etc..
   unique_together(code, name)

class Settings(Model):
   gameCode = charField(). #Didn't use Foreign key because of internal reasons where we can't use Games model somewhere outside
   username = charField()
   ...

class GameCodeChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.name

class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   gameCode = GameCodeChoiceField(queryset=None,required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ['username']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['gameCode'].queryset = Games.objects.filter(game=game, isActive=True)
        self.fields['gameCode'].to_field_name = 'code'
```

Now, When i try to save SettingsForm, I'm getting GameCode = 'GameCode Object' instead of the code like `GTA`..

Please help. Edited.

Comment: You did not set any base class your form will inherit from.

Comment: I have set that to forms.ModelForm.

Comment: And please check the code you posted! It has a lot of typos and indentation errors.

Comment: @KlausD. Forgive me, that this is not real code. I'm changing model names  to keep corporate info private.

Comment: Typos and Indentation errors are not causing the issue.

Comment: https://snakeycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/django-dynamic-modelchoicefields/

This seems like a solution but i'm not sure how it works

Comment: I think you are confused by the representation of your object after you save it. Please show how you are verifying that it is getting saved wrongly.

Comment: I don't know your `gameCode` on `Settings` model is a `CharField` but u assigned it with queryset on `SettingsForm` init.

Answer (score 1):

`to_field_name` changes the values of the generated option elements, not the display text.

You want to add a `__str__` method to your model. It will change the display of each object instance listed in the select element.

```
Class Games(Model):
   code = charField()  # GTA, ABC, etc..
   name = charField()  # Grand Tourismo, ALL BBB CCC , etc..
   unique_together(code, name)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.code
```